# javascript syntax error expected expression, got '<'

Tags: javascript, firefox, syntax, syntax-error

so I have this code:

```
;
(function (g) {
  var d = document, i, am = d.createElement('script'), h = d.head || d.getElementsByTagName("head")[0], aex = {
    "src": '',
    "type": "text/javascript",
    "async": "true",
    "data-vendor": "acs",
    "data-role": "gateway"
  };
  for (var attr in aex) {
    am.setAttribute(attr, aex[attr]);
  }
  h.appendChild(am);
  g['acsReady'] = function () {
    var aT = '__acsReady__', args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0), k = setInterval(function () {
      if (typeof g[aT] === 'function') {
        clearInterval(k);
        for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
          g[aT].call(g, function (fn) {
            return function () {
              setTimeout(fn, 1)
            };
          }(args[i]));
        }
      }
    }, 50);
  };
})(window);
```

when you run it through the console in Firefox, it'll complain

"SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'"

However, when you try it out in http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html, it works just fine...

what does it do wrong?

Comment: I just run in Google Chrome's console and Firefox console and it's works.

Comment: In Firefox its apparently different

Comment: chrome silently ignores it but on firefox it  still will make the network request as @frontend_dev mentioned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this line is problematic:

```
"src": '',
```

So you have in essence a blank src. The error itself indicates that you get some HTML in response, in this case apparently the browser just tries to load the page you are currently on (watch the network panel). But try to use something more meaningful with your src, or leave it out completely if you just want to create a script tag.

Comment: Ah and seriously, *explain* when you downvote. I hate that and I will just stop trying to help if that continues that way.